# Android Studio, Google Maps Search Button is not working

Tags: java, android-studio

i worte an Android Application with google Maps integration. 
I found a tutorial in youtube and did it in that way like in the video to search a location with button click.
I have just simple plaintext and a button for search. The Button is set to the onclick method onSearch() you can find code bellow.

When i press on that button, the app is crashing. What is wrong in the Code??

Thank you in advance:

```
public void onSearch(View v){

        //Textfield in google maps activity
        EditText location_tf=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFadress);
        //Put the written input into a string to work with
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();

        //List for Geocoder
        List<Address> addressList= null;

        if(location!= null || !location.equals("")){
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList=geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng= new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Searched Location"));

            //MovetheCamera to the searched location with 18 zoom
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
        }

}
```

Error Log:

08-18 13:25:36.182 2619-2619/com.group6.travlhoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.group6.travlhoe, PID: 2619
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5336)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5331)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.group6.TakeOff.MapsActivity.onMapSearch(MapsActivity.java:84)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5331) 
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)